# Instr function assistance

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have built logic to fetch the data using 2 fields and using instr and I need to search for exact pattern matching in the below. However I am getting different pattern match output as well. Can anyone pls help on this.Also I wanted to use instr only not any regular match functions like regex_inst:

```
**Input** : attr_value and object_name are the field names.
```

| attr_value | object_name |
| --- | --- |
| select 'exec test_INC.MC_INS_SO_STAT;' FROM DEFAULTDB | test_INC.MC_INS_SO_STAT |
| select 'exec test_INC.MC_INS_SO_STAT_Anom | test_INC.MC_INS_SO_STAT |
| select 'exec test_INC.MC_INS_SO_ST;' |  |

```
**Output** :
```

| attr_value |
| --- |
| select 'exec test_INC.MC_INS_SO_STAT;' FROM DEFAULTDB |
| select 'exec test_INC.MC_INS_SO_STAT_Anom' |

```
**Expected Output**:
```

| attr_value |
| --- |
| select 'exec test_INC.MC_INS_SO_STAT;' FROM DEFAULTDB |

I have tried this logic: IIF (INSTR (upper(attr_value),upper(OBJECT_NAME)) > 0 ,1, 0 )
but its giving me different pattern too as mentioned in output which is not as per my expected output. If you can pls help how to tweak the logic to fetch the exact match records only.

Comment: `IIF` in Oracle? You sure? At any rate, I don't get the same results: https://dbfiddle.uk/rSYaDtER

Comment: @JNevill-I have replicated scenario for you based on yours.https://dbfiddle.uk/An18Jxlb Can you pls help

Comment: basically,I wanted to check the exact match within this. 2nd record select 'exec test_INC.MC_INS_SO_STAT_Anom' is not match as it contains '_Anom' so this record should be discarded.

Comment: Gotcha. So ultimately this matching is like "Is this full word contained within this sentence" type of thing. I have to ask though, what is your aversion to regex? It feels perfectly suited this as word boundaries are a built in feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not quite clear what is the logic behind your expected output from sample data provided. If it is that you want to fetch the row where ATTR_VALUE contains OBJECT_NAME followed by semicolon and single quote with some more text after that then it could be done like below:

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl (ATTR_VALUE, OBJECT_NAME) AS
        ( Select 'select ''exec test_INC.MC_INS_SO_STAT;'' FROM DEFAULTDB', 'test_INC.MC_INS_SO_STAT' From Dual Union All 
          Select 'select ''exec test_INC.MC_INS_SO_STAT_Anom''', 'test_INC.MC_INS_SO_STAT' From Dual Union All 
          Select 'select ''exec test_INC.MC_INS_SO_ST;''', Null  From Dual
        )
```

```sql
--    S Q L :
Select ATTR_VALUE
From   tbl
Where  InStr(ATTR_VALUE, Nvl(OBJECT_NAME, '*****') || ';''') > 0 And 
       Length( ATTR_VALUE) > 
       Length(SubStr( ATTR_VALUE, 1, InStr(ATTR_VALUE, OBJECT_NAME || ';''') -1) || OBJECT_NAME || ';''')
```

```sql
/*       R e s u l t :
ATTR_VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------
select 'exec test_INC.MC_INS_SO_STAT;' FROM DEFAULTDB       */
```

... If it is just about containing OBJECT_NAME followed by semicolon and sigle quote then you can get the same row with just the first WHERE clause condition:

```sql
...
Where  InStr(ATTR_VALUE, Nvl(OBJECT_NAME, '*****') || ';''') > 0
```